# Prepop fields with values when another field is checked in Django

Tags: python, django

In my Django database I have the following:

```
skipUserPII = models.BooleanField(default=False)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
address1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Sometimes, I will create a user manually. In that case, I won't want to fill in their PII every time. So I have created a new variable "skipUserPII" that if checked fills in all PII values with "na" (as compared to having to manually fill in all my PII fields with some default value, allowing me to save the form in Django admin).

I'm trying to accomplish this by using the following code below, however it is giving me a "Please correct the errors below" error.

```
def clean(self):

    if self.skipUserPII == True:
        def checkNone(field, value):
            if field == None: field = value

        checkNone(self.first_name, 'NA')
        checkNone(self.last_name, 'NA')
        checkNone(self.address1, 'NA')
```

I've tried putting this in `clean` and in `save` -- neither work. Is there another place this code should go?

Answer (score 0):

`field` is a local to the `checkNone` function and thus won't affect the call site.

Why fill those fields with `"NA"` though instead of keeping those fields nullable or blankable?
What about the poor foreigner whose name is NA NA? How will you be able to tell them from a no-PII user?

Comment: The reason for this is I want to make other changes to the user profile, but can't save the user profile at all if I don't fill something in there. So maybe I want to fill in their firstname and lastname now, but don't know their address -- I can't just save the two fields.

Comment: Set `blank=True` and/or `null=True` on the fields if they can be blankable/nullable?

Comment: Yeah, but then I have a modelForm elsewhere in my app -- and I want the fields to be required there (all good suggestions though)

Comment: Then you'd have the requiredness validation in that ModelForm.